# \left[ and \right] resizing differently for very similar formulae. Don't know how to fix it.

Tags: formatting, brackets

I have a `\newcommand` which inserts left and right square brackets around whatever you pass it.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\begin{document}
    Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_j b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_i c_i C_i}$ by definition.
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Notice that the square brackets around the sum in the C equation are much smaller than those in the B equation. Why is this happening and can I avoid having to manually change the size each time? I am using these square brackets a lot throughout a large document and would really like to avoid it.

Comment: I would say, this is the cause of the descender of the letter `j` -- contrary to `i` which doesn't have this descender.

Comment: Hmmm.. You are correct that it does seem that changing `j` to `i` makes the B brackets small as well. That is a shame as I think the second equation looks ugly with the sigma going outside of the square brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The different height of the brackets is caused by the descender of the letter `j` compared to `i`.

One way: Use `k` instead of `j` (or any other letter without descender)

Or perhaps using `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` is an option (or if scaling isn't an issue `\big[` and `\big]`?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\bigl[#1\bigr]}
\begin{document}
    Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_j b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_i c_i C_i}$ by definition.
    \hrule
\end{document}
```

The `\hrule` is just for comparison only. Certainly, there are other ways to achieve this.

Note: `\big[` etc. works too, but the scaling is different. It's a matter of taste rather then a law.

[image]

Comment: I am going to use `\big` for now as this at least makes the sizing consistent. I think I will define a different function `\bar` for with `\biggr` brackets for expressions with sum in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another way: you could `\smash` the `j`s.

Comment: One could also take the biggest formula and add it as a `\vphantom`, thus eliminating the need to try out the sizes of different brackets

Comment: @Turion: I hadn't seen your comment, I think as you that `\vphantom` is  what is natural to use in such a case, I made it an answer.

Comment: @Joce, that's perfectly fine :) I was just too lazy to write a whole answer.

Answer (score 5):

A simple fix for these annoying little size mismatchs in otherwise similar formulas is to use `\vphantom` :

```
Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_j b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_{i\vphantom{j}} c_{i\vphantom{j}} C_{i\vphantom{j}}}$ by definition.
```

One `\vphantom` should be sufficient of course, in the present case, the one of the `\sum` operator as its subscript is typeset lower than others.

Alternatively, if you'd rather have all of the same height, you can use `\smash` on the `j` subscripts, as suggested by WChargin in a comment. This is useful if the formula is in a multiline paragraph and you want to reduce the extra line spacing.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\begin{document}
Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_{\smash{j}} b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_i c_i C_i}$ by definition.
\medskip

Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_j b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_{\vphantom{j}i} c_i C_i}$ by definition.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just perfect as well. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Compared to the accepted solution, it is a technique that doesn't modify the whole of the document's typesetting, which will generally be thought of an advantage for such a cosmetic problem--although you mention that in your case you want the whole document to behave the same.

Comment: You can also use `\strut` which is defined as `\vphantom{(}`.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is having a minimum size automatically:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\minsize}{\vrule width 0pt height 1.5ex depth 1ex\relax}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\left[\minsize #1\right]}
\begin{document}
    Since $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum_j b_jB_j}$ and $\foo{C} = \foo{\sum_i c_i C_i}$
by definition.

Now it will scale up --- but not down:  $\foo{B} = \foo{\sum\limits_\frac{j}{j} b_jB_j}$
\end{document}
```

...but then it will make the smaller ones too big: 
[image: Example]

You can adjust the minimum size playing with the `height` and `depth` parameters of the rule defined in `\minsize`.